# Как удалять файл который создан через FileOutputStream

Tags: java, filestream

Мне нужно удалять файл каждый раз когда нажмаеться кнопка, но файл создан используя FileOutputStream:

```
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
 fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_APPEND);
fos.write("Data".getBytes());
fos.close
```

Но метода для удаления файла нет, как можно его удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы удалить файл, созданный с помощью FileOutputStream, можно использовать метод File.delete().
Например, чтобы удалить файл с именем fileName, можно использовать код:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```